# Conditional Formatting for items created in the last 5 minutes in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, xpath, sharepoint-2010, conditional-formatting

All,

I've been looking all day and have tried numerous solutions, but just can't get it to work. Our team projects a list that is constantly updated and we want to highlight only newly created items for 5 minutes. After 5 minutes, the row would return to normal. (FYI- the list is projected on a display and updated using AJAX asynchronous update every 15 seconds)

Basically, I want to set conditional formatting on list items created in the last 5 minutes. If the item was created in the last 5 minutes, the row will be highlighted. After the 5 minutes are up, the row would return to normal.

I tried SharePoint Designer conditional formatting by creating a calculated column in Date/Time format called "Created + 5" and tried to set an expression where the formatting is applied (row is highlighted) when "Created + 5" is greater than or equal to current date. So after 5 minutes, the row will no longer be highlighted (because the current date/time will exceed the "Created + 5" value)

Here is the expression from the SPD Advanced Condition Builder:

**ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($thisNode/@Created_x0020__x002b__x0020_5_x))) >= 
ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))**

I think the problem is that the [Current Date] option ($Today in the expression builder) only accounts for date and not time. It looks like it just ends up highlighting everything that was created today, which is not very useful.

Any thoughts or help!? I have never messed with the advanced conditions because usually the basic stuff works fine for me! If anyone has any other ideas too like JavaScript or anything else that would work, I am open to that too as long as it will continuously update!

Thanks all!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Today] actually doesn't work properly in 2010, there are some workarounds though, e.g. https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/.

You can also use the approach with calculated column: https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was avoiding calculated columns and trying to figure out how to do it in SPD. $Today works in the conditional formatting because it's XSL but it only pulls the day and not the time....

Answer (score 0):

Since you want this to update automatically without requiring someone to manually refresh the page, JavaScript is your best bet. You can have a function run repeatedly on a specified interval, checking the current date against the values in a date column.

Something like the following code would work, though you may need to tweak the CSS selectors specified in the calls to `document.querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to match your particular HTML.

```
<script>
formatCell();
function formatCell(){
    var frequencyToCheck = 2 /* num seconds between updates */
    var minutes = 5; /* num minutes back to highlight */
    var targetColumn = "Display name of the column you want to check";
    var formatting = "background-color:darkred;color:red;font-weight:bold;";
    var comparisonDate = new Date();
    comparisonDate.setHours(comparisonDate.getHours() - minutes);
    var tables = document.querySelectorAll("table.ms-listviewtable"); /* should get all list view web parts on the page */
    var t_i = 0;
    while(t_i < tables.length){
        var headings = tables[t_i].rows[0].cells;
        var columnIndex = null;
        var h_i = 0;
        while(h_i < headings.length){
            var heading = headings[h_i].querySelector("div:first-child");
            if(heading != null){
                var displayName = heading.DisplayName ? heading.DisplayName : (heading.innerText ? heading.innerText : heading.textContent);
                displayName = displayName.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); /* removes leading and trailing whitespace */
                if(displayName === targetColumn){
                    columnIndex = h_i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            h_i += 1;
        }
        if(columnIndex != null){ /* we found a matching heading */
            var rows = tables[t_i].rows;
            for(var i = (rows.length > 0 ? 1 : 0); i < rows.length; i++){
                var cells = rows[i].children;
                if(cells.length <= columnIndex){continue;}
                var valueToEval = cells[columnIndex].innerText ? cells[columnIndex].innerText : cells[columnIndex].textContent;
                if(typeof valueToEval == "undefined"){valueToEval = "";}
                valueToEval = new Date(valueToEval);
                if(valueToEval > comparisonDate){
                    cells[columnIndex].setAttribute("style",formatting);
                }else{
                    cells[columnIndex].setAttribute("style","");
                }
            }
        }
        t_i +=1;
    }
    setTimeout(formatCell,frequencyToCheck * 1000);
}
</script>
```

One potential pitfall is that while this approach will "age" records appropriately based on their displayed values (causing them to stop being highlighted as they grow stale), it won't automatically pick up new changes to the list; you'd need to refresh the page (or at least refresh the view in the web part) whenever you want to see updated information.